# UIButton colored line at the bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uibutton

I have a UIView witch contains four UIButtons and all the buttons have a image placed in the background of them. But the two buttons on top get some sort of colored line at the bottom of them. This only happens when I test the app on my device, not when I run it on the simulator. I was wondering if anyone know how to get rid of the line. Is there any settings I’ve missed or something like that?

Image 1:
http://hdev.se/asd/bild.PNG

Image 2:
http://hdev.se/asd/bild2.PNG

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its weird, are your sure there is no line on the image?

Comment: In particular (since it happens on device and not simulator), check your Retina (@2x) images if you're using any.

Comment: If the frame of the UIImageView is not exactly the size of the image, it could try to do something funky for the last line

Comment: Check the color profile of the image. Sometimes that can cause lines to appear.

Comment: did you run it on the simulator with iOS version same as that on device?

Comment: Yes, both is are of the same version

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found the following solution:

The problem was caused by the images I used. I saved them as PNG-8 files. When I changed them to PNG-24 files the problem was gone. It seems that the reduced color palette was causing the problems.